# Right shift not working as expected

Tags: php

I need to do some bit twiddling to pull out some data I'm getting from another source.

The data I've got looks like this in binary:

```
01100011 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Which is the little-endian encoding of the decimal number 99.

I want to mask (bitwise-and) it with this value:

```
01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

And then shift all the way to the right (30 places).

When I try right-shifting it, however, I get:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00110000
```

And I can't figure out why.

Here's the code:

```
function binrep($bin,$len=32) {
    return implode(' ',str_split(str_pad(decbin(hexdec(bin2hex($bin))),$len,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT),8));
}


function mask($data,$pos,$len=1,$size=32) {
    $bits = (1<<$len)-1;
    $shift = $size - $pos - $len;
    $mask = pack('N',$bits << $shift);
    echo binrep($data)."\n".binrep($mask)."\n".binrep(($data&$mask)>>$shift);
    return ($data & $mask) >> $shift;
}

mask(pack('V',99),1);
```

Where is that value coming from? Why isn't the result

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

?

Comment: print the values of the variables ( $bits!) and you'll see.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Huh? How is printing them in non-binary format going to help me? `$data & $mask` is `@` and when right-shifted is `0`, which tells me PHP is probably just interpreting the first byte. I don't see how this helps answer my question though. `$bits` is `1` which is exactly what I expect.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Could be...I think it just doesn't like right-shifting multibyte values though.

Comment: `bin2hex(0)` gives "30". That's where that value is coming from. Regardless, the value shouldn't be 0.

Comment: Is the original 32 bit value an integer? If so, PHP should put it into a register (fixing the byte order and the bit order, if necessary) before masking and shifting. All you have to worry about are "big endian" masks (decimal 64 in this case) and the amount to shift (no more than 6 bits). If the original is a string or something non-integer, all bets are off.

Comment: @PhilPerry: The original comes as an attribute value in XML. It's trivial to convert it into a PHP int, but it needs to be interpreted as a little-endian 32-bit integer for the bits to be in the right place... but then it becomes a binary string, so I have to convert it back so that I can shift it (as elitechief pointed out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type mismatch.  Since `($data & $mask)` evaluates to a string, php is implicitly changing the type of `$shift` to a string to do the operation. And as per the php documentation, this means the `>>` operator is using ascii values to do the calculation. I added this function to your code:

```
function decrep($bin)
{
return hexdec(bin2hex($bin));
}
```

then did the shift to the right using this function `binrep(pack('N',((decrep($data) & decrep($mask)) >> $shift)))` and this gives the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

A full solution for anyone that needs to pull out random bits from a 32-bit int:

```
function decrep($bin) {
    return hexdec(bin2hex($bin));
}

function binrep($bin,$len=32) {
    return implode(' ',str_split(str_pad(decbin(hexdec(bin2hex($bin))),$len,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT),8));
}

function extractBits($data,$pos,$len=1,$size=32) {
    $bits = (1<<$len)-1;
    $shift = $size - $pos - $len;
    $mask = pack('N',$bits << $shift);
    return (decrep($data) & decrep($mask)) >> $shift;
}
```

Usage:

```
$result = extractBits($data,1,2); // pulls out the 2nd and 3rd to left bit, returns number in range 0-3
```